# laptop wifi hotspot with samsung galaxy ace

Tags: wireless-networking

i ve used a no of softwares including windows 7 internet sharing to use my Ethernet connection in laptop through wifi for my samsung galaxy ace. it connects and provides browsing for some time but after a while network remains connected but no browsing. can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your phone is connected to your computer, but your computer has no connection.
Make sure your laptop ethernet connection works.

Also try disconnecting and connecting again, or making a new hotspot